# How to use sigPeak() function in quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, technical-indicator

I cannot grasp how to properly use [`sigPeak()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantstrat/versions/0.14.6/topics/sigPeak) in [quantstrat](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantstrat/versions/0.14.6).

A (not working) example follows.

I add an indicator to `mktdata`:

```
add.indicator(strategy = name,
              name = 'WinDoPar',
              arguments = list(x = quote(OHLC(mktdata)),
                               n = 300,
                               w = 'run',
                               fun = RSI_dens),
              label = 'pti',
              store = TRUE)
```

It should produce a column named `X1.pti` because of the label, and actually it does. Then I would like to use `sigPeak()` to add a signal:

```
add.signal(strategy = name,
           name = 'sigPeak',
           arguments = list(data = mktdata,
                            column = 'pti',
                            direction = 'peak'),
           label = 'pti.buy',
           store = TRUE)
```

There's an additional argument required by `sigPeak()`, which is `label`: however, I didn't get how to use it. Thus, when I add a rule like this and apply the strategy, it fails:

```
add.rule(strategy = name,
         name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol = 'pti.buy',
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 1,
                          ordertype = 'market',
                          orderside = 'long',
                          replace = TRUE,
                          osFUN = osTotSize,
                          acct.name = name,
                          TxnFees = TxnFees),
         label = 'pti.buy.enter',
         type = 'enter',
         store = TRUE)
```

Error thrown:

```
Error in applyRules(portfolio = portfolio, symbol = symbol, strategy = strategy,  : 
  mktdata does not contain 'sigcol': pti.buy
```

A closer inspection of `mktdata` revelas there is a column labelled like this: `pti.buy.peak.sig.pti.buy`, which seems quite odd.

So how am I supposed to use `sigPeak()` to generate a signal to buy after indicator's peaks?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source, `sigPeak` generates a signal when you effectively have a 'triangle' pattern in the underlying time series, and fires  a signal when the "triangle" is complete. It makes sense to use this signal in combination with others to generate a meaningful trade signal (maybe smooth the sigPeak time series with `EMA`, etc to make it more robust, and act on it breaching some threshold value between 0 and 1, etc)

Your error is telling you 'pti.buy' is not a column name in `mktdata`. So your `add.rule` needs to change the `sigcol = "pti.buy"` argument to whatever the name is of the column containing your entry signal. Sounds like it should be `sigcol = "pti.buy.peak.sig.pti.buy"` and then things should work.

On closer inspection of `sigPeak`, it looks like the name of the column output from `sigPeak` takes the form [label].peak.sig.[label] when `direction = "peak"` or [label].valley.sig.[label] when `direction = "valley"` (using `direction = "bottom"` current generates an error in `sigPeak`, due to an error in the switch code inside `sigPeak`).  Not exactly intuitive.

An easy way to use `sigPeak` is to modify the function and pass that in as the function for `add.signal`. I do this with `sigPeak2` below.

Here is a reproducible example using `sigPeak` that might help:

```
library(quantstrat)
strategy.st <- "RSI"
initEq=100000
port.st<-'RSI'

rm.strat(strategy.st)
stratRSI <- strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, name = "RSI", arguments = list(price = quote(getPrice(mktdata))), label="pti")


sigPeak2 <- function (label, data, column, direction = c("peak", "bottom"))  {
    if (!is.numeric(column)) {
        colNum <- match.names(column, colnames(data))
    }
    else colNum <- column
    direction = direction[1]
    switch(direction, peak = {
        ret_sig <- Lag(data[, colNum], 2) < Lag(data[, colNum],
                                                1) & Lag(data[, colNum], 1) > data[, colNum]
    }, bottom = , valley = {
        ret_sig <- Lag(data[, colNum], 2) > Lag(data[, colNum],
                                                1) & Lag(data[, colNum], 1) < data[, colNum]
    })
    if (!missing(label))
        colnames(ret_sig) <- label
    return(ret_sig)
}


add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name = 'sigPeak',
           arguments = list(data = quote(mktdata),
                            column = 'pti',
                            direction = 'peak'),
           label = 'drop')

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name = 'sigPeak2',
           arguments = list(data = quote(mktdata),
                            column = 'pti',
                            direction = 'bottom'),
           label = 'jump')

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, name="sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(threshold=70, column="pti",relationship="gt", cross= TRUE),
           label="RSI.gt.70")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, name="sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(threshold=60, column="pti",relationship="lt", cross= TRUE),
           label="RSI.lt.60")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, name="sigFormula",arguments = list(formula = "RSI.gt.70 == 1 & jump == 1"),label="enterLong")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, name="sigFormula",arguments = list(formula = "RSI.lt.60 == 1 & drop.peak.sig.drop == 1"),label="exitLong")


add.rule(strategy = strategy.st, name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="enterLong",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty= 100,
                          TxnFees=0,
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='long',
                          pricemethod='market',
                          replace=FALSE),
         type='enter', path.dep=TRUE)

add.rule(strategy = strategy.st, name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="exitLong",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty='all',
                          TxnFees=0,
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='long',
                          pricemethod='market',
                          replace=FALSE),
         type='exit', path.dep=TRUE)



currency("USD")
symbols = c("SPY")
stock.str = symbols

startDate <- "2013-01-01"


getSymbols(stock.str,from=startDate, to= Sys.Date())


for(symbol in symbols){
    stock(symbol, currency="USD",multiplier=1)
}


initPortf(port.st, symbols=symbols)
initAcct(port.st, portfolios=port.st, initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio=port.st)


for(symbol in symbols){ addPosLimit(port.st, symbol, timestamp = startDate, maxpos = 1000) }

applyStrategy(strategy=strategy.st, portfolios=port.st)

updatePortf(strategy.st)
updateAcct(strategy.st)
updateEndEq(strategy.st)


chart.Posn(strategy.st, Symbol = 'SPY', Dates = '2000::')
```